# How to save PID to variable in bash -c?

Tags: bash, variables, pid

I'm having trouble with saving the PID into a variable when I'm using `bash -c`. For example:

```
bash -c "PID=$$; echo $PID"
```

In this case the output is empty. How to save the child PID (the PID of the command inside the double quotes) now in the variable `PID`

Comment: Which PID do you mean? The PID of your currently running bash shell, or the shell you are starting?

Comment: @hetepeperfan The PID of the child command inside the double quotes.

Comment: would you please make that clear in your question so that future readers, Take the most benefit of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set -x` is useful for debugging and will show the actual command you end up running prefixed with `+`:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "PID=$$; echo $PID"
+ bash -c 'PID=1900; echo '
```

And indeed, in that command you would expect empty output. This happens because `$$` and `$PID` are substituted *before* `bash` is called.

To avoid this, you can single quote the string or escape the "$"s:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c 'PID=$$; echo $PID'
+ bash -c 'PID=$$; echo $PID'
1925
$ bash -c "PID=\$\$; echo \$PID"
+ bash -c 'PID=$$; echo $PID'
1929
```

Answer (score 2):

just use simple quotes or you expression is evaluated inside your current command line (too soon) and not in the child bash command, and `PID` isn't defined yet at this moment and you're actually passing

```
bash -c "PID=4353; echo"
```

(where 4353 is the pid of the current bash process)

Someone noted that it's not clear if you want to pass parent pid or child pid

to pass parent pid, fix it like this (only the part within double quotes is evaluated *before* calling bash child process):

```
bash -c "PID=$$; "'echo $PID'
```

to pass child pid, fix it like this (nothing is evaluated in the current shell, same trick used for `awk` scripts):

```
bash -c 'PID=$$; echo $PID'
```

Comment: OP is a bit unclear whether the PID of the parent bash shell should be taken or the newly started bash shell. +1 for stating both options!

Comment: What is when I have to use simple quotes inside the child-command?

Comment: @hetepeperfan XY problem again ! I have added both possibilities in my answer. Maybe the "pass parent" one is the most useful. There's no use passing its own process id to child process.